# how to address big heap issue and garbage collection pauses

Tags: java, c++, performance, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am working in a company in which they care a lot about performance read/write both. And we mostly are using Java as the language in our company and Geronimo servers.

Few days back there was the discussion between our team and our Architects on what we can do to improve the  performance. And in that meeting our architect mentioned that we need to do something to address the "big heap problem in Java" and Java Garbage Collection pauses.

He was totally against Java GC pauses and big heap problem in Java. But frankly speaking, I was not able to understand why these two things or anything else in Java/JVM can cause so much bad performance. And our architect were mainly in favor of C++ servers and C++ language.

Now my question is- I am not able to understand why he was saying that because of big heap problem in Java and Garbage Collection pauses, Java is not suitable for our use case in which we need to make sure performance of read/write is top-notch.

Can anyone provide me detailed understanding why he was against Java in big heap problem and garbage collection pauses as compared to C++ and why he was suggesting let's go with C++ servers and as the language as well. I saw various other stackoverflow post to understand why he was against it but somehow due to my lack of deep understanding, I am not able to understand those solutions. So any step by step detailed explanation will make things more clear to me.

Any help will be appreciated on this. Thanks

Comment: "Why he was against big heap problem and garbage collection pauses" - who would be *for* these things?

Comment: @Oli, that's what I am trying to understand. You can see my intent in my question what I am looking for. Just a detailed understanding of this what can cause bad performance.

Comment: This link may help you http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-rtj4/ Java now has a real-time garbage collector which reduces the pauses at the expense of more CPU usage.

Comment: @brianbeuning, Thanks for the link. One quick question, sorry if it sound too bad. Why pauses can cause bad performance? Any thoughts will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: @user21973: are you asking "Why is pausing the whole program causing my program to run slower"?  Just think about that for a second...

Comment: So that means it doesn't do GC pauses in the background task, it will pause all the threads that are doing the main tasks and run a seperate thread to do the GC?

Comment: @user21973 If your process is interacting with people, they usually expect snappy response times.  Pauses are not snappy.  Using a non Java GC with a 2 GB heap I measured a 6 second pause and thats assuming low page faults.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic memory allocation and garbage collection, regardless of language, slow down performance.  With statically or limited allocations, there is no need for dynamic memory allocation or garbage collection.

The C and C++ languages do not come with garbage collection.  Dynamic memory allocation is provided by the platform (OS or Compiler Library).  Garbage collection is up to the Programmer.  This allows flexibility for the Programmer.

Java comes with dynamic memory allocation and also garbage collection.  One question that comes up with language provided garbage collection is "when does garbage collection run?"  For example, will the program at one point suspend while the program performs garbage collection?  Or will garbage collection be performed as a background task?

You will need to study dynamic memory allocation and garbage collection to get a background.  Next, ask the architect to clarify or explain his or her reasoning.

Another issue is that Java is compiled into an intermediate language call Java Byte Codes.  The Java Byte Codes need to be executed by a Java Virtual Machine (not the native processor).  With C and C++, the code is compiled into native processor instructions; no interpretation required.  The C or C++ executable is tied to the platform environment and must be rebuilt in order to run on another platform.  Java is more platform independent and runs on any platform that has a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: I think that last paragraph needs clarifying; Java *is* compiled, it just happens to be compiled to target the JVM.  And the JIT typically translates large chunks to native instructions as well.

Comment: Reworded.  The issue is not about an interpretation per se, but having the JVM on top of the native processor executing the Byte Code.

Comment: I thought Java could be compiled to machine code instead of byte codes.  It still has the JVM but it is more like the C runtime environment.

Comment: @brianbeuning In theory yes, and I think there are somewhat-working implementations that do this, but the mainstream implementations do JIT compilation and it's generally faster. The JIT compiler outputs machine code too, with similar performance (assuming C compiler and JVM JIT compiler do an equally good job, which isn't a given), and also uses the JVM services mostly like a run time library.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to dealing the with pauses from garbage in Java.

- use a concurrent collector like Zing.  They can get 1-4 ms worst case jitter and this is better than some C++ programs due to jitter from other sources (i.e. GC is not the only cause of jitter)
- create less garbage and use off heap memory. In C++, everything is effectively off heap and really, anything you can do in C++ you can do in Java even if it is not as natural.

Here is an example from a real high frequency trading system. It did a full GC once per day at 5:00 AM when not trading and the Eden size was 8 GB, larger than the amount of garbage produced in a day.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html

From The [OpenHFT/Java-Lang](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang) project you can do this.

```
final DirectStore store = DirectStore.allocate(128L << 32); // give me 128 GB
final DirectBytes slice = store.createSlice();

// every record has say 128 bytes and a lock at the start so they can be locked individually
for(long l = 0; l < store.size(); l += 128) {
    slice.positionAndSize(l, 128);
    slice.busyLock(0L);
    // change something
    slive.writeLong(4L, l);
    slice.unlock(0L);
}

// when finished with the store
store.free(); // still no GCs.
```

So in this example, I have created and initialised one billion records.  This uses almost no JVM heap and doesn't trigger any GCs.

If you are concerned that code might not be compiled when you need it to be, you can trigger the code to be compiled in advance by exercising it.  Take one or two of your unit tests and exercise the critical code until it compiles.  This can usually be done in less than a second.

In short, if GCs are a concern there are always solutions.  You can develop solutions in Java with a latency of 19 micro-seconds external to the box which doesn't trigger any GCs (even minor ones)

> why he was suggesting let's go with C++ servers and as the language as well.

Most developers don't know how to write low latency Java.  In C++ there are more developers who do and this can be reason alone to use C++.  However, it is not a feature of the language which prevents low latency, just a lack of skills in the Java space.

Comment: It almost certainly uses "the heap", just likely "the heap" of the C or C++ runtime library, or perhaps it grabs a range of pages from the OS. It just doesn't do it in memory that's governed by any GC (Java or otherwise).

Comment: @delnan Fair point, I have added an example from a real low latency trading system.